# LibGDX MainMenu with ScrollPane - Select Level and press Play

Tags: libgdx, menu, gui

In my level Menu, I am using tables that have images and text to identify each game level. 
Those tables are in a table that is inside a ScrollPane so the player can browse the levels available.

Here is how i've written the code:

```
//top of my show() method

    stage = new Stage();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor((com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor) stage);

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("levelsmenu/levelmenu.pack");

    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("levelsmenu/liststyle.json"), atlas);



//example of the tables with image and text identifying each level

    tableLevel1 = new Table();
    tableLevel1.add(new Image(skin, "rhlevelone"));

    tableLevel1.add(new Label("THE HOOD", skin));


//table with the levels available

    Table levelList = new Table(skin);
    levelList.add(tableLevel1);
    levelList.row();
    levelList.add(tableLevel2);
    levelList.row();
    // etc.

// ScrollPane

    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(levelList, skin);

// 
table3.add(scrollPane).padLeft(220).expandY();

//
stage.addActor(table3);
```

On the stage I have a button to go back to the Main Menu and a button to play the level selected.

I would like to request help to figure out how to set the right listeners so a level can be selected in the ScrollPane and then played cliking the Play Button.

Should I use FocusListener or ClickListener?

Here is an illustration of what I want do do:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help that may come!!!

Rich Days

Answer (score 3):

This is the logic:

- Create `ImageButtons` or `TextButtons` first
- Add these to a `Table`
- Create a `ScrollPane` with the `Table`
- Set `ScrollPane` position and size. You can disable scrolling in a direction using `scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled()`
- Add `ScrollPane` to the `Stage`

Answer (score -1):

Try using ChangeListener, i've never used a ScrollPane but I did some UI's using ChangeListener!

Comment: This answers needs some additional meat.  More implementations details, pseudo-code, or something.  Right now your advice is too vague to be useful.